# how to send string constant to a field value using dozer mapping?

Tags: java, dozer

```
'<mapping map-id="vehicle Info">
  <class-a>vehicle Info</class-a>
  <class-b>uninsured</class-b>

  <field>
     <a>CONSTANT_CAR</a>
     <b>car.value</b>
  </field>
</mapping>'
```

I'm trying to send the constant value of "CONSTANT_CAR" into the field of "car.value" which is located inside the vehicle

Can someone please guide me how can I pass the constant value to a setter which is located in the destination class.

Comment: have you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the constant by setting the 'is-accessible="true"' for the constant field.  So, your mapping could look something like this:

```
<mapping map-id="vehicle-info">
  <class-a>path.to.VehicleInfo</class-a>
  <class-b>path.to.Uninsured</class-b>

  <field>
     <a is-accessible="true">CONSTANT_CAR</a>
     <b>car.value</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

Make sure when naming the classes in the `<class-a>` and `<class-b>` tags you put the full path to the class.

I just tested with some sample code and it mapped the constant as expected.  Let me know if it works for you!